# amCharts label font settings

Tags: label, amcharts

I have a stylesheet on my app that sets a baseline font. It works fine and I'm happy with it.

```
* {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

I'm adding a label to the center of a pie chart. The label is added correctly, but fontSize has no effect. I would think that being so explicit would override any other styles, but it doesn't?

```
chartOverviewAnimatedCenterLabel = chartOverviewAnimated.seriesContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
chartOverviewAnimatedCenterLabel.text = "";
chartOverviewAnimatedCenterLabel.horizontalCenter = "middle";
chartOverviewAnimatedCenterLabel.verticalCenter = "middle";
chartOverviewAnimatedCenterLabel.fontSize = 50;
chartOverviewAnimatedCenterLabel.id = "center";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define font size on axis. something like this

```
let categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 8;
```

Comment: It's a pie chart though i.e. no category axis?

Comment: oh My bad. see it this helps https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/piechart-with-too-many-slices/#Reduce_font_size